# Maximum Likelihood Estimation Uniform Distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood

A sample is drawn from the uniform distribution:

$X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}:U(0,2\theta )$

I am interested in finding the MLE for $\theta$.

My intuition say that

$\hat{\theta }=max(X_{i})/2$

How do I explain it mathematically ?

The likelihood function is:

$L = \frac{1}{2^{n}\cdot \theta ^{n}}$

which is not differential if I am not mistaken. How do I get $\hat{\theta }=max(X_{i})/2$ then ?

Comment: You have to show that this value $\hat\theta$ you propose is the value that maximises the likelihood. Differentiating is not necessary. (_Hint:_ the likelihood function is missing an indicator.)

Comment: This is a popular textbook question which you can find discussed [in many threads here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+uniform+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1+answers%3A1+-prior).